# making the service inspector to return an custom object instead of an fault exception in c#

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, client-server, inspector

I'm making a service inspector to validate the soap request coming in against the xsd. i want to make the AfterReceiveRequest method to reply back with a proper response (not the fault exception) to client before it reaches the service, if there is anything wrong with the request payload.

my AfterReceiveRequest method,

```
en      public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy (int.MaxValue);

        try
        {
            Message messageCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();
            XElement payloadTovalidate = Helper.GetXmlPayload(messageCopy, _payloadStartTag);

            if (payloadTovalidate != null)
            {
                CustomValidator validator = new CustomValidator();
                validator.Validate(payloadTovalidate.ToString(), _interfaceName);
            }
            else
            {
                return new CustomException(string.Format("ERROR: Incorrect xml format in the payload or attachment. Expected object of type {0} ;", _payloadStartTag), "asd", "asdas");

            }
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            throw new FaultException(exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            request = buffer.CreateMessage ();
            buffer.Close ();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Changing the service wouldn't be an option since, there are quite a lot.

Comment: You need to use `faultContract` for that and use your own exception type.

Comment: Does your validation need to be on the `Message`? If you did validation on a later extension point (for example an `IOperationInvoker`) it would be much easier to return a response.

Comment: @ErnieL yes. I need the validation results to be on a proper soap response. how does the IOperationInvoker thing work? when would that get triggered?

Comment: IOperationInvoker is the last extension point just before your service class is called. As such you can completely override the response object (stopping the service call doesn't require throwing an exception). See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/17/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker.aspx